# Since when did XML Schema URL used in spring start supporting only from over TLS1.2?

Tags: java, spring, ssl, xsd

I built a web application with Spring 3.2.18.RELEASE, JDK7, and Tomcat7 before.

Lately I deployed some jsp files and restarted Tomcat and It showed me this error message.

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 130; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

It turned out that I set the xsi:schemaLocation to '**https**://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd'

and it wasn't possible to load the xml because of TLS version of JDK.

---

So I googled when the schema xml stopped supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

but I couldn't find any.

I already got to know I need to upgrade Spring, JDK, and Tomcat by reading dozens of articles.

I hope somebody can tell me **WHEN** it happened or

it'd be thankful at least let me know where to find it.

ps. I couldn't find the answer on [www.springframework.org](http://www.springframework.org). I tagged 'spring-boot' here because it says I can get help by that.

---

**UPDATED**

I'm sorry my question was ambiguous.

Thanks to a number of articles and comments here, I got to know how to solve my problem and it worked great.

The reason I posted this question is that

if I add -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 option, my webapp works fine just like before.

If I change it into TLSv1.0 or v1.1, I can see exactly same error message.

The webapp worked fine without it before and now it requires the option at least on JDK7.

My colleague said 20,Oct was the last time she restarted Tomcat and it was fine.

So I believe something happend between 20,Oct and yesterday.

Comment: The problem with that URL is that it isn't substituted in Spring 3.2 and thus goes to the internet. Instead use http and it will resolve it from file (it is included in the jar file) and it doesn't need an internet connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum You are right. I already saw spring-beans-3.2.xsd in spring jar. So I bolded 'https'. I also know TLS1.0 and 1.1 is much less secure than 1.2 so I can understand they are no more supported. Question is WHY TLS version became a problem NOW and since WHEN they started not being supported.

Comment: Please read my comment. The support for TLS is irrelevant here. The point is that Spring 3.2 doesn't support resolving to file for https yet (those aren't in the spring.schemas file) thus it goes to the internet instead of resolving from the jar. The latter is what shouldn;t be happening (but is because no https alias is in the spring.schemas file). With newer versions of Spring it doesn't matter if it is http or https they areboth resolved from the jar not from the internet.

Comment: @M.Deinum If the url starts with 'https' in spring 3.2.x, it doesn't resolve it. I know. To run the webapp in the current circumstance, I must change it into http and TLS is irrelevant as you said. Absolutely no argue with that. But think of this. If I add '-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2' option and restart Tomcat, it works fine again even if it's still https. That's why I posted this question. The webapp worked fine until I restarted Tomcat yesterday even without the JVM option. And I heard from my colleague it was fine on 20, Oct. I believe something happened between 20, Oct and yesterday.

Comment: No you don't need to change it to https... What makes you think you need/must change it to https... It isn't a URL it is a namespace.

Comment: @M.Deinum Maybe, my english is the problem... ##### It's ok to change it to http. That will work. But it was fine with https before and now it doesn't work. That's the point. I thought 'https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd' was supported with TLSv1.0 and v1.1 before but now it is supported only from over TLSv1.2.

Comment: If it worked then something else broke... It sholdn't even resolve it from the internet in the firest place. So TSL, nor HTTPS is the issue. The problem is why it isn't resolving it from the jar.

Comment: @M.Deinum I think www.springframework.org had changed its TLS supporting policy. They supported TLSv1.0 and v1.1 before and now They doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly when [www.springframework.org](http://www.springframework.org) stopped supporting TLSv1.0, 1.1

but I'm sure it might be between 20, Oct and 10, Nov.

---

Recently, many browsers start to stop supporting TLSv1.0 and 1.1 because of security measure.

And I think that's why [www.springframework.org](http://www.springframework.org) did it.

---

Folks.

Please DO upgrade your JDK or at least TLS in advance. ( T^T)